# Type or namespace not found for user control

Tags: asp.net, iis

Tonight I copied an ASP 2.0 web site onto a client's machine, and lo!  It did not work.  It works perfectly on mine, under built in debugger and under IIS 7, and two weeks ago, it worked perfectly on his machine under IIS 6.

The only changes I have made are upgrading telerik RadGrid etc. to Q1 2009, and some refactoring.  The application fails on two entry point web forms.  Both have a RadGrid, which uses a User Control for its editing pop-up.  Both forms fail to compile, with a 'Type or namespace `JobEditControl` not found" error, on a line like this:

```
var editControl = e.Item.FindControl(GridEditFormItem.EditFormUserControlID) as JobEditControl;
```

The control is not referenced in the markup, as it never appears on there, and as I understand it, it should be compiled into the same default namespace as the page is compiled into when first hot.

The machine is still serving user controls properly, i.e. the .ascx handler appears healthy, and a quick test page containing a quick test control I added worked fine.

Another developer was busy on the machine before me, also installing an ASP.NET application, but I can't think of anything he would have changed.  Even being my competition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the web.config has a reference to the current version of the telerik's controls.

Comment: The web.config has _never_ had a reference to the telerik controls, and still doesn't, but it still works on my machine.  It isn't required when they are located in the bin folder, only when they are located in the GAC.

Comment: @ProfK y, as you didn't say anything about it, I thought it would be that. During the refactoring did you move pages/controls to different folders? depending on the web site model you are using that can affect you.

Comment: Nope, no moves to different folders.  I always try and avoid any folder structure in early prototyping.  I only did some refactoring of data access classes within the App_Code folder.